# Oracle Database 10g: Refresh Production Database Schemas to Stage Database with not all production data

Tags: oracle10g

Hi Oracle DBA Gurus, Is there an easy way to do to refresh production database schemas to stage database with smaller amount produciton data (not all production data)? Both databases are 10g r2.

Answer (score 1):

For the schemas? Yes, there exists numerous solutions for this. For the data? I don't believe there is a generic way to do this. Since your data is unique for you, it's impossible to build a generic solution copying a subset of data, taking into account relationships, triggers, stored procedures etc.

Depending on what data you have, it might not be hard to do manually anyway. Once you have working solution, it can be very handy for a long time with small efforts in updating.

Comment: thx, for just DDL I understand that using rows=N as an option when doing import. but can I do something like rows=2000? when doing import?

Comment: Have a look at the impdp and expdp programs, and their parameter QUERY. That might give you an idea of how to proceed. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1006293